# Edit string array elements

Tags: java, arrays, json

My array is like this:

```
"keys": [
        "first name",
        "second name",
        "date of birth",
        "name",
        "tle no",
        "other details"
    ]
```

I want to re-arrange above array data like this:

```
"keys": [
            "first_name",
            "second_name",
            "date_of_birth",
            "name",
            "tle_no",
            "other_details"
        ]
```

I want to create it using java code. How can I create it?

Comment: I assume `date of_birth` should be `date_of_birth`.

Comment: How do you have that array? That is not a Java array. Where is your java code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `String.replaceAll()` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    keys[i] = keys[i].replaceAll(" ", "_");
}
```

Reference: [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace  (space) by `_` then just use `string.replace(" ", "_"`)`